# Unable to run executable link

Tags: 13.04, executable, .desktop

I added a link to the desktop using Nautilus ("Make Link"):

```
me@1234:~/Desktop$ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 alex alex 4096 Sep  8 12:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 42 alex alex 4096 Sep  8 00:22 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 alex alex   41 Sep  8 12:14 Android Studio -> /opt/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

But when I run it, it just open this file in gedit. What do I do about that?
And

```
ls -al /opt/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex 6505 Jul 11 23:48 /opt/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Comment: could you paste there the desktop file too , which you have created. that will help us.

Comment: @rajagenupula The OP didn't create a desktop file, only a symlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **Nautilus**, go to **Edit** → **Preferences**, select **Behavior** tab and tick **Run executable text files when they are opened** or (what I prefer) **Ask each time**:

[image]